# How to get the first symbol of a string

Tags: java, android, string, unicode

I need to display the first symbol of a string. The simpliest code for this would be:

```
String text = "test string";
char firstSymbol = text[0];
```

But this doesn't work if the character doesn't fit 16 bits, for example `"\uD83D\uDC68"` (, `U+1F468`). Only half of the character is returned and it is rendered as question mark.

```
String text = "test string";
int codePoint = text.codePointAt(0);
char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);
String firstSymbol = new String(chars);
```

This works well for any character that is represented in Unicode. However, there are sequences of Unicode characters are displayed as one symbol. When I run the code above for them only part of symbol is displayed as it happens for `"\uD83D\uDC68\u200D\uD83D\uDCBB"` (‍). In this case I want the result to be the whole string. How can I handle such cases?

---

It should be charAt() of course, my fault. But `char` is UTF-16 encoded and can't contain several characters. The first example should be this:

```
String text = "test string";
char firstSymbol = text.charAt(0);
```

---

Another tough example for one symbol is `"\u0D23\u0D4D\u200D"` (ണ്‍). It has two characters and zero-width joiner at the end.

---

I have tried to use `android.icu` library, which descends from `ICU4J`, but unfortunately it is supported only starting from API 24. Moreover it produces the same result as the second example, i.e. it doesn't join characters if zero-width joiner is between them.

```
int breakIterator = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
breakIterator.setText(text);
int begin = breakIterator.first();
int end = breakIterator.next();
String firstSymbol = text.substring(begin, end);
```

Comment: "But this doesn't work if the character doesn't fit 16 bits" -> It does not work because the syntax (`char firstSymobl = text[0];`) is wrong. I think you meant to use `text.charAt(0)` (which will not fix your "more than 16 bits"-problem)

Comment: you can use text.substring(0,1) it will give you first character of string.but before doing that, please check string would not null.

Comment: @Lucky It would return a `String` of size 1, not a `char` :) The method to get a character from a `String` is `charAt(int index)`

Comment: Fixed it, please see the updated question. I also suppose that the string is not null and also not empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u200D` is Unicode codepoint `U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER`.  If you want to extract a sequence of joined codepoints, you are going to have to iterate the string manually until you encounter a non-joined codepoint, eg:

```
String text = ...;
StringBuilder sequence = new StringBuilder(text.length());
boolean isInJoin = false;
int codePoint;

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i = text.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1))
{
    codePoint = text.codePointAt(i);

    if (codePoint == 0x200D)
    {
        isInJoin = true;
        if (sequence.length() == 0)
            continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((sequence.length() > 0) && (!isInJoin)) break;
        isInJoin = false;
    }

    sequence.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
}

if (isInJoin)
{
    for(int i = sequence.length()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (sequence.charAt(i) == 0x200D)
            sequence.deleteCharAt(i);
        else
            break;
    }
}

String firstSymbols = sequence.toString();
```

Alternatively:

```
String text = ...;
boolean isInJoin = false;
int start = 0, length = 0, next;
int codePoint;

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i = next)
{
    codePoint = text.codePointAt(i);

    if (codePoint == 0x200D)
    {
        isInJoin = true;
        if (length == 0)
        {
            next = text.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1);
            start = next;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((length > 0) && (!isInJoin)) break;
        isInJoin = false;
    }

    next = text.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1);
    length += (next - i);
}

if (isInJoin)
{
    for(int i = length-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (text.charAt(i) == 0x200D)
            --length;
        else
            break;
    }
}

String firstSymbols = text.substring(start, start+length);
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you use [Zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)`(\u200D)` character to join emojis, you can [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) your `String` by this character:

```
String[] result = text.split("\u200D");
```

And get first character in the next way:

```
String firstSymbol = result[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning zero-width joiner, I'll try to learn more about this. However I need to get both emojis that are joined in order the result to be displayed correctly. I'll try to iterate the string and join emojis if they are separated by zero-width joiner.

Comment: When you split a `String` by zero-width joiner, you'll get array of Strings, and you can iterate through them to get all the emojis one by one.

Comment: I've implemented it, but it doesn't work well as too many corner cases appear. Please look at the updated question.